# Pack empty rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Given this table in columns X Y and Z;

```
 <b>X   Y   Z</b>
 A      
     B  
         C
 D      
     E  
         F
```

I would like to "pack" the data together and get this result:

```
 <b>X   Y   Z</b>
 A   B   C
 D   E   F
```

A macro that takes the selected cells/table and "pack" them with the click of a button would be great.

Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You tagged it [tag:excel-vba] but I see no code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need an excel macro for this, just use Go to->Special->Blanks, then delete all the blanks cells by shifting the cells up.

You can get there by pressing f5 in excel, or from Find&Select under the home tab.